# Difference between querySelector() and querySelctorAll()

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

I would like to know whats the difference between `querySelector()` and `querySelctorAll()`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`querySelector()` returns a single element, `querySelectorAll()` returns a node list of elements it can find

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid

Answer (score 1):

These two methods allows you to target all the HTML elements without worrying about the type of CSS selectors.

`document.querySelector(your CSS selector);`

`document.querySelectorAll(your CSS selector);`

This [Blog](https://simrancodes.hashnode.dev/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-in-javascript) Might Help you to understand more Clearly

Answer (score 0):

Both method interact with DOM from JavaScript.

Don’t use ID selectors with `querySelector`. The IDs that you define in HTML templates may be transformed into globally unique values when the template is rendered. If you use an ID selector in JavaScript, it won’t match the transformed ID

```
<template>
  <div>First</div>
  <div>Second</div>
</template>
```

Here are few difference in both.

**querySelector()**

- Select the first element that matches a specified CSS selector within the shadow DOM
- This method return first element as `HTMLElement`
- If no element matches the specified selector, it returns `null`
- Elements not rendered to the DOM aren’t returned in the `querySelector` result.

Example:

```
    this.template.querySelector("div"); // <div>First</div>
    this.template.querySelector("span"); // null
```

**querySelectorAll()**

- Select all elements that match a specified CSS selector within the shadow DOM
- The order of element is not guaranteed
- This method return list of `HTMLElement`
- If no element matches the specified selector, it returns empty array

```
this.template.querySelectorAll("div"); // [<div>First</div>, <div>Second</div>]
```

In latest release Refs introduce which could be useful for some of the cases. for more details you can go through the latest release.

**Reference :**
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-components-dom-work.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid