# Uncaught TypeError: this.template.querySelector(...).changeMessage is not a function error in LWC SalesForce

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I am beginner in salesforce and now practicing lwc session by doing event handling task. And the practice tasks includes the child component method invocation from parent component.When I created the components and loading the parent component via local development server , I am getting the message that app:5348 Uncaught TypeError: this.template.querySelector(...).changeMessage is not a function in console and not getting any response in parent,

Here is the console screenshot,

[image]

My parent component name is parentCmp. and my parentCmp.js is like the following,

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ParentCmp extends LightningElement {


handleChangeEvent(event){
    
   this.template.querySelector('div').changeMessage(event.target.value);
   }
 }
```

And parentCmp.html,

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Parent to Child Demo">
    <lightning-layout>

        <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto" padding="around-small"  >
            <lightning-input label="Enter the Message" onchange={handleChangeEvent}> 
            </lightning-input>
        </lightning-layout-item>
      
        < <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
            <div></div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
      
      </lightning-layout>
   </lightning-card>   
 </template>
```

parentCmp.js-meta.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="parentCmp">
  <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
 </LightningComponentBundle>
```

My child component js file is childCmp.js,

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
export default class ChildCmp extends LightningElement {

 @track Message;

 @api
 changeMessage(strString) {
     this.Message = strString.toUpperCase();
   }
 }
```

And package.xml is like the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="https://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <types>
     <members>*</members>
     <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
  </types>

  <version>52.0</version>

</Package>
```

I debugged the component by cross checking the component definition in xml files and syntax. But still getting the same error. Can anyone guide me or provide related documentation to resolve this problem please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to execute the `changeMessage` method on the `div` element, which doesn't have this method. Try to add your child component to the markup of the parent one, and query it like this:

```
const childComponent = this.template.querySelector('c-child-cmp');
if (childComponent) {
    childComponent.changeMessage(event.target.value);
}
```

instead of the piece of code you have in the parent component's `handleChangeEvent` method

Look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_javascript_methods) about how to execute a method from the child LWC.

Comment: Your code works perfect. But when I add code in single line like `this.template.querySelector('c-child-cmp').changeMessage(event.target.value);` , then its not working. its giving `Uncaught TypeError: this.template.querySelectorAll(...).changeMessage is not a function ` error. Can you please guide me what is the difference I am making here wrong ?

Comment: Yes, because the querySelectorAll is a different thing than the querySelector, and returns a node list of elements found. So, basically, you're trying to call a method from the list of elements but not the element itself. Check my answer here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/396126/82956